# Logo Upload working in brackets but not live through CyberDuck

Tags: html, css

I have designed a web page for a friend but when I try to change the H2 Logo for a png image. It does not seem to want to load.

The strange thing is however, that the .PNG file works in the Brackets Application. But not live on the server.

The webpage is here: http://www.donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk/

It is supposed to look like this: (Brackets Preview)

[image: How it Should look- (Brackets preview)]

This is from the Index.HTML code, which I will write below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home | Donja's Well-Being For Kids</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Indie+Flower|Shadows+Into+Light|Shadows+Into+Light+Two" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="favicon" type="image/png" href="img/Kids-Well-Being.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="index.html">
        <img id="logo" src="img/Donjas-Well-Being-For-Kids.png" alt="Donja's-Well-Being-For-Kids">
        <!--
        <h2 id="logo" class="centerText">Donja's Well-Being For Kids</h2>
        -->
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
      <div  class="banner">
        <img src="img/Kids-Well-Being-Health.jpg" alt="Kids Health">
      </div> 
      <br/>
      <div class="welcomeBar">
        <h2>Welcome To</h2>
        <h2><q>Donja's Well-Being For Kids</q></h2>
        <p><q>......Helping children to become calm, confident and resilient, by understanding and regulating their emotions, through Relax Kids&trade; and Emotional Literacy classes and workshops.</q></p>
      </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <ul id="collections">
          <li>
              <a href="emotionalLiteracy1-1Support">
                <img src="img/Emotional-Literacy-1-1-Support.jpeg" alt="Emotional Literacy 1 on 1 Support">
                <p>Emotional Literacy 1-1 Support</p>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="relaxKids">
                <img src="img/Relax-Kids-Online.jpg" alt="Relax Kids">
                <p>Relax Kids&trade;</p>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="tipsToHelpYourChild">
                <img src="img/Tips-To-Help-Your-Child.jpeg" alt="Tips to Help Your Child">
                <p>Tips To Help Your Child</p>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="helpWithParenting">
                <img src="img/Help-With-Parenting.jpeg" alt="Help With Parenting">
                <p>Help With Parenting</p>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="classesAndWorkshops">
                <img src="img/Classes-And-Workshops.jpeg" alt="Classes and Workshops">
                <p>Classes and Workshops</p>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="testimonials.html">
                <img src="img/Testimonials.jpg" alt="Testimonials">
                <p>Testimonials</p>
              </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <footer>
<!--        <a href="http://twitter.com/lukebennettuk"><img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>-->
        <a href="http://facebook.com/Donjaswellbeingforkids" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <p>&copy; 2017 Donja's Well-Being For Kids.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS is here:

```
    /*******************************************
GENERAL
********************************************/

body {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
/*  background-image: img/shining-blue-water-background.jpg;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
}

.centerText {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}



/*******************************************
HEADING
********************************************/

header {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5px auto;
}



/*******************************************
NAVIGATION
********************************************/

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
}



/*******************************************
BANNER
********************************************/

.banner {
  display: block;
  margin: -30px 0 0px 0;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.banner img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}



/*******************************************
WELCOME BAR
********************************************/

.welcomeBar {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.welcomeBar h2 {
  margin: 0;
}



/*******************************************
TOP BOX
********************************************/

.topBox {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #659EB8;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.topBox i {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 6px;
}



/*******************************************
FOOTER
********************************************/

footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.social-icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}



/*******************************************
PAGE: HOME: COLLECTIONS
********************************************/

#collections {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#collections li {
  float: left;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 2.5%;
}

#collections li a img{
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: #f5f5f5; 
}

#collections li {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#collections li a p {
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 40%;
  left: 52%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  transition: .5s ease-out;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#collections li a:hover p {
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 105%;
}



/*******************************************
PAGE: ABOUT
********************************************/

.profile-photo {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}



/*******************************************
PAGE: CONTACT
********************************************/

.contact-info {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.contact-info a {
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.contact-info li.fax {
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-position: left 3px bottom 5px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.contact-info li.phone a {
  background-image: url('../img/phone.png');
}

.contact-info li.mail a {
  background-image: url('../img/mail.png');
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.contact-info li.fax {
  background-image: url('../img/printer.png');
}

.contact-info li.facebook a {
  background-image: url('../img/facebook.png');
}



/*******************************************
PAGE: EMOTIONAL LITERACY
********************************************/

.emotionalLiteracy {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}



/*******************************************
PAGE: RELAX KIDS
********************************************/

.relaxKids {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.relaxKids li {
  margin: 0 17px;
}

.chill-skills-photo {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  border-radius: 2%;
}



/*******************************************
PAGE: TIPS TO HELP YOUR CHILD
********************************************/

.tips {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tips li {
  margin: 0 17px;
}



/*******************************************
PAGE: HELP WITH PARENTING
********************************************/

.parenting {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.parenting-banner {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}



/*******************************************
PAGE: CLASSES AND WORKSHOPS
********************************************/

.workshops {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

iframe {
  border: none;
  overflow:hidden;
}



/*******************************************
PAGE: TESTIMONIALS
********************************************/

.testimonials-lydia {
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.testimonials-lydia p {
  margin: 5px 17px 0;
}

.testimonials-benjamin {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.testimonials-benjamin p {
  margin: 5px 17px 0;
}

.testimonials-gabby {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.testimonials-gabby p {
  margin: 5px 17px 0;
}

.testimonials-amy {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.testimonials-amy p {
  margin: 5px 17px 0;
}

.testimonials-isabelle {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.testimonials-isabelle p {
  margin: 5px 17px 0;
}

.testimonials-johnny {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.testimonials-johnny p {
  margin: 5px 17px 0;
}


/*******************************************
COLORS
********************************************/

/* site body */
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

/* grey header */
header{
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}

/* nav background on mobile */
nav {
  background: #D4BDD7;
}

/* links */
a {
  color: #000;
}

/* nav link */
nav a, nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

/* selected nav link */
nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
  transition: .5s;
}

p.littleStars {
 color: blue; 
}

.welcomeBar {
  background-color: #659EB8;
}

#collections li a p {
  color: black;
  background: rgba(235, 229, 235, .3);
}

#collections li a:hover p {
  background: rgba(235, 229, 235, .9);
}

.emotionalLiteracy {
  background-color: #F15369;
  color: white;
}

.relaxKids {
  background-color: #8B5D8D;
  color: white;
}

.tips {
  background-color: #ECE272;
  color: black;
}

.parenting {
  background-color: #F4B97B;
  color: black;
}

.workshops {
  background-color: #71A87B;
  color: white;
}

/* testimonial boxes */
.testimonials-lydia {
  background-color: #F15369;
  color: white;
}

.testimonials-benjamin {
  background-color: #F4B97B;
  color: white;
}

.testimonials-gabby {
  background-color: #ECE272;
  color: white;
}

.testimonials-amy {
  background-color: #71AB7B;
  color: white;
}

.testimonials-isabelle {
  background-color: #2e619f;
  color: white;
}

.testimonials-johnny {
  background-color: #8B5D8D;
  color: white;
}
```

The CyberDuck Server files are organised like this:

[image: CyberDuck Files - Everything]

[image: CyberDuck Files - Img Folder]

Please help, I cannot seem to get the logo to appear how I would like. I have tried renaming it, uploading CSS and Index files from scratch so they exactly math Brackets. But still get nothing. Don't really understand what I am doing wrong.

Many Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Did you [clear the browser *cache*](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/)?

Comment: Omg, it is working. Thank you. I knew it would be something ridiculous. Can't believe I have been searching for ages. It will be the first thing I check next time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why the logo is showing smaller on the contact.html page:

Do you know why this might be:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Contact | Donja's Well-Being For Kids</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Indie+Flower|Shadows+Into+Light|Shadows+Into+Light+Two" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link rel="favicon" type="image/png" href="img/Kids-Well-Being.png">
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <a href="index.html" id="logo">
            <img id="logo" src="img/Donjas-Well-Being-For-Kids.png" alt="Donja's-Well-Being-For-Kids">
            <!--
            <h2 id="logo" class="centerText">Donja's Well-Being For Kids</h2>
            -->
          </a>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <!------------ PRODUCTS -------------------------------------
              <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
              ------------------------------------------------------------->
              <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <div id="wrapper">
          <section id="primary">
            <h3>General Information</h3>
            <p>For more details please contact me.</p>
            <p>I have a current DBS Certificate and also Public Liability Insurance.</p>
          </section>
          <section id="secondary">
            <h3>Contact Information</h3>
            <ul class="contact-info">
              <li class="phone"><a href="tel: 07916 337 916">Phone: 07916 337 916 </a></li>
              <li class="mail"><a href="mailto: Donja@Donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk">Email: Donja@donjaswell-beingforkids.co.uk</a></li>
              <li class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/1724861014479447" target="_blank">CLick to Message me on Facebook!</a></li> 
            </ul>
    <!--
            <h3>Hours of Operation</h3>
            <p>Monday - Friday 8:00am - 5:30pm</p>
            <h3>Address</h3>
    -->
            <p></p>
          </section>
          <footer>
    <!--        <a href="http://twitter.com/lukebennettuk"><img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>-->
            <a href="http://facebook.com/Donjaswellbeingforkids" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
            <p>&copy; 2017 Donja's Well-Being For Kids.</p>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Preview]

The site is working. If its not working for you clear you cache or do a force refresh / hard refresh.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you. Do you know why the logo would be showing smaller on the contact page than any other page?